# Is there a way to use TeX programmatically from a custom text editor?

Tags: editors, programming-tools

What I mean is, is there something like a `tex.dll` that I could use to incorporate TeX's functionality inside a custom text editor?

For various reasons, and specific purposes, I am writing "the simplest possible" text editor for my own use, and it seems quite productive on paper. However, I will be using maths heavily and I don't want to reinvent the wheel of this enormity.

I am not sure how TeX could return a piece of formatted content but for maths formulas, which is what I really want, a jpeg should work fine for me.

If what I am looking for doesn't exist, what could be done to incorporate TeX generated formatted maths into my text editor?

FYI, I am developing in C++ on Windows 7 using plain Win32 API.

PS: I couldn't find appropriate tags and have used what seemed closest.

Comment: TeXStudio can insert a preview of e.g. an equation. Emacs imho too.

Answer (score 1):

This is built-in on Mac OS X --- just use a text editor which supports Services, install LaTeXiT and one can type an equation, typeset it in place and un-typeset it to restore the source.

For Windows you should be able to achieve something similar by using OLE and accessing an equation editor.

You may want to look at TeXmacs or TeXworks.

Comment: I didn't quite find anything right away, but the mention of OLE has helped - I never thought about that. I'll continue the search a bit later. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I sometimes use LyX as it seems better than TexWorks. I tried using TeXMacs after you posted but it doesn't even start on Windows 7, not sure why. But my motivation has a heavy programatical bent to it as well, so am keen on that elusive dll like component.